# Difference between nil and @"" in NSMutableString iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablestring

I want to know the difference between `nil` and `@""` in `NSMutableString`.

I need to clean string value in `NSMutableString` every second.

So

```
myMutableString = nil;
```

or

```
myMutableString = @"";
```

Which one is better to clean and why?

Comment: This smells like homework *sniff*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

---

In the case of a mutable string, you have to alloc/init it first like this:

```
NSMutableString *myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Maybe you have done that, but then you have to reset the string like this:

```
[myMutableString setString: @""];
```

So instead of writing `myMutableString = @""`, use the code above.

---

If you assign `myMutableString` to `nil` it is not a valid pointer/object and cannot respond to messages or actions. If you actually set it to `@""`, it is a totally valid object which can respond to messages, methods and actions, it is just contains a string with a length of 0.

```
myMutableString = nil;

[myMutableString appendString: @"It now contains a valid string!"];
```

This cannot happen since the string is `nil`

```
myMutableString = @""; 

[myMutableString appendString: @"It now contains a valid string!"];
```

This can happen, `myMutableString` is a valid object and can respond to messages. And guess what, it now has a string!

So, a string object can still be initialized and have have an actual string value without any characters. Just like an array can be valid and have 0 objects inside it. Otherwise, how would you add to it!?

However, In an `NSMutableString`'s scenario, you may have to actually alloc-init it.... somebody please clarify.

Obviously, assigning to `@""` is better, it actually depends on your scenario though. I don't know why you would want to assign to `nil`, unless you are reassigning the variable to a new string object.

Comment: `[@"" appendString: @"It now contains a valid string!"]` will throw unrecognized selector exception

Comment: @xlc0212 **What** are you talking about!? Let me reword my question if that is what you think I meant.

Comment: `@""` is `NSString` not `NSMutableString`. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'

Answer (score 2):

None of them

use

```
[myMutableString setString: @""];
```

to reset your string.

Your object remains the same. You invoke a method that clear its content.